# How can I send text from a textarea to a form?

Tags: forms, text, textarea

I want to know how I can send text from a textarea to a form by clicking on a button. Both the textarea and form are on the same page. I've searched the site and the web but can't find the right answer. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: ...huh?  You'll need to clarify what you want to do...you have some field in the form that's there to receive the contents of the textarea?  Or is the textarea in the form already (in which case it just needs a name in order to submit the contents)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="html_form_action_here" method="post">
   <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="text_area">
   </textarea>
</form>
```